# Iterate over numpy array columnwise

Tags: python, numpy

`np.nditer` automatically iterates of the elements of an array row-wise. Is there a way to iterate of elements of an array columnwise?

```
x = np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])

for i in np.nditer(x):
    print i

# 1
# 3
# 2
# 4
```

What I want is:

```
for i in Columnwise Iteration(x):
    print i
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

Is my best bet just to transpose my array before doing the iteration?

Comment: "Is my best bet... transpose...?" Maybe you can explain the context - *why* would you like to iterate over all columns? Depending on the answer transpose might be reasonable or not, and maybe iteration is unnecessary.

Comment: @AmiTavory I need to fill values into an array based on the index of each cell in the array. It's a little bit complicated to explain, but I want to do the iteration columnwise instead of rowwise to match a similar function that exists in R, where iteration over a matrix occurs columnwise by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, you don't necessarily have to transpose the matrix before iterating through the elements.  With `np.nditer` you can specify the **order** of how to iterate through the matrix.  The default is usually row-major or C-like order.  You can override this behaviour and choose column-major, or **FORTRAN**-like order which is what you desire.  Simply specify an additional argument `order` and set this flag to `'F'` when using `np.nditer`:

```
In [16]: x = np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])

In [17]: for i in np.nditer(x,order='F'):
   ....:     print i
   ....:     
1
2
3
4
```

You can read more about how to control the order of iteration here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#controlling-iteration-order

Comment: That `doc` page is a must for anyone trying to use `nditer`.  But study it all the way to the end if you want any speed improvements (compared to regular array iteration).

Comment: @hpaulj for sure :)!

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose it?

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
>>> [y for y in x.T]
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

Or less elegantly:

```
>>> [np.array([x[j,i] for j in range(x.shape[0])]) for i in range(x.shape[1])]
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

Comment: Never mind. It happens. Am going to erase my comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the shape and slice each column

```
>>> [x[:, i] for i in range(x.shape[1])]
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 2):

`nditer` is not the best iteration tool for this case.  It is useful when working toward a compiled (cython) solution, but not in pure Python coding.

Look at some regular iteration strategies:

```
In [832]: x=np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])

In [833]: x
Out[833]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [834]: for i in x:print i   # print each row
[1 3]
[2 4]

In [835]: for i in x.T:print i   # print each column
[1 2]
[3 4]

In [836]: for i in x.ravel():print i   # print values in order
1
3
2
4

In [837]: for i in x.T.ravel():print i  # print values in column order
1
2
3
4
```

You comment: `I need to fill values into an array based on the index of each cell in the array`

What do you mean by `index`?

A crude 2d iteration with indexing:

```
In [838]: for i in range(2):
   .....:     for j in range(2):
   .....:         print (i,j),x[i,j]
(0, 0) 1
(0, 1) 3
(1, 0) 2
(1, 1) 4
```

`ndindex` uses `nditer` to generate similar indexes

```
In [841]: for i,j in np.ndindex(x.shape):
   .....:     print (i,j),x[i,j]
   .....:     
(0, 0) 1
(0, 1) 3
(1, 0) 2
(1, 1) 4
```

`enumerate` is a good Python way of getting both values and indexes:

```
In [847]: for i,v in enumerate(x):print i,v
0 [1 3]
1 [2 4]
```

Or you can use `meshgrid` to generate all the indexes, as arrays

```
In [843]: I,J=np.meshgrid(range(2),range(2))

In [844]: I
Out[844]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1]])

In [845]: J
Out[845]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])

In [846]: x[I,J]
Out[846]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Note that most of these iterative methods just treat your array as a list of lists.  They don't take advantage of the array nature, and will be slow compared to methods that work with the whole `x`.