# Why did using range just speed up my code 2x?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, iteration

I had a bit of code where I essentially iterated through a numpy array to decide which elements would stay and which would go. I am planning to parallelize it with [JobLib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) as that worked for a different part of my code. To do that, I had to get it into a nice simple for loop. In attempting to do that, I reformed my code in a similar way to this pseudocode:

```py
for i in range(np_arr.shape[1]):
    output[t] = self.do_a_thing([t, i, column[i]]) # notice column[i]
```

Where `t` is just a value that changes and `column` is the current working column of the array. `column[i]` refers to 1 element in column, and replaces my first implementation,

```py
for i in column:
   do_a_thing(...)
```

Interesting, the for loop with the range statement ran over twice as fast (920ms vs 2500 ms) as the direct implementation. My theory is that range is doing "range-y" things in native c versus numpy. I've also heard that range in python 3 is more efficient than in python 2 because it doesn't actually generate a list.

What has invaded my code to make it not only work but work faster by a very noticeable amount?

Comment: The two fragments really aren't similar enough to compare. Is the only difference really just that one uses `i` and the other `column[i]`?

Comment: How are you iterating over columns exactly in the 2nd example? To iterate over columns: `for col in np_arr.T:` or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35513753/6091318)

Comment: Can you include a complete example, including how column, np_arr, and other variables are defined?  As it is now neither fragment will run, plus things such as size and datatype can have an effect on the relative speeds.

Comment: Agree that's it's unclear from your examples, but from my read, it almost looks like in the "original" code you're looping through all elements in the column, while the "new" code is voctorized to operate on the whole column at once (which is the bread and butter of numpy)

Comment: @chepner Sorry, should have been more clear about that, you are right. That is the only difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are right that python's range is not creating a list, it is making a generator (which is more efficient). While numpy tends to be faster for huge and complex operations on matrices and vectors, the overhead of going between python and numpy's highly-optimized C code often makes it slower for very simple tasks like this.

I've found that python's range almost matches the performance of a small C function to do the same purpose, but both far surpass the speed of numpy for simple things like this.

Comment: Nitpick, `range` does not return a generator, it returns a `range` object (`range` is just a constructor). `range` objects are efficient containers that represent integral ranges, and implement the sequence interface. They are not even iterators, let alone generators, but they are iterable